# Trailing slashes in Pylons Routes

Tags: python, routes, pylons

What is the best way to make trailing slashes not matter in the latest version of Routes (1.10)? I currently am using the clearly non-DRY:

```
map.connect('/logs/', controller='logs', action='logs')
map.connect('/logs', controller='logs', action='logs')
```

I think that turning minimization on would do the trick, but am under the impression that it was disabled in the newer versions of Routes for a reason. Unfortunately documentation doesn't seem to have caught up with Routes development, so I can't find any good resources to go to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two possible ways to solve this:

1. [Do it entirely in pylons](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Adding+trailing+slash+to+pages+automatically).
2. [Add an htaccess rule to rewrite the trailing slash](http://enarion.net/web/apache/htaccess/trailing-slash/).

Personally I don't like the trailing slash, because if you have a uri like:

http://example.com/people

You should be able to get the same data in xml format by going to:

http://example.com/people.xml

Comment: Easily guessable URLs are good, so people ought to be allowed to go to /people and /people/ and see the same thing.  Canonical URLs are also good, so one of those should redirect to the other.

Answer (score 16):

The following snippet added as the very last route worked for me:

```
map.redirect('/*(url)/', '/{url}',
             _redirect_code='301 Moved Permanently')
```

Comment: I'm 90% sure I found it somewhere on the net, but I cannot provide a proper attribution at the moment.

Comment: This works and is a lot simpler than all the other solutions.  You deserve upvotes, good sir.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/275 has a basic piece of middleware which removes a  trailing slash from requests. Clever idea, and I understood the concept of middleware in WSGI applications much better after I realised what this does.